# Not write out all dates on an axis, Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Take a look at this example:

```
import datetime as dt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
x = []
d = dt.datetime(2013, 7, 4)
for i in range(30):
        d = d+dt.timedelta(days=1)
        x.append(d)

y = range(len(x))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.bar(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The code writes out dates on the x-axis in the plot, see the picture below. The problem is that the dates get clogged up, as seen in the picture. How to make matplotlib to only write out every fifth or every tenth coordinate?

[image]

Comment: What about rotating the date labels 90 degrees? `plt.xticks(rotation=90)`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can specify an `interval` argument to the `DateLocator` as in the following. With e.g. `interval=5` the locator places ticks at every 5th date. Also, place the `autofmt_xdate()` after the `bar` method to get the desired output.

```
import datetime as dt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
x = []
d = dt.datetime(2013, 7, 4)
for i in range(30):
        d = d+dt.timedelta(days=1)
        x.append(d)

y = range(len(x))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=5))
plt.bar(x, y, align='center') # center the bars on their x-values
plt.title('DateLocator with interval=5')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image: Bar plot with ticks at every 5th date.]

With `interval=3` you will get a tick for every 3rd date:

[image: Bar plot with ticks at every 3rd date.]

Comment: Are we able to define the start date and end date?

Comment: Worked for me! Spent SO much time trying to find this out. Thanks!