# How can I change datetime format of x-axis values in matplotlib using python?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, matplotlib, plot

How can I make this plot's x-axis looks better?

Is there any way to show only 3 values in x-axis while plotting all values in my dataframe?

[image]

I tried using `plt.xticks(rotation=70)` but it still cuts my numbers..

As you can see, it shows the date in the format `MMM DD YYYY`.

> I wanna something like `MMM DD` or `DD MMM`. Or even writing in 2
>   lines `DD MM \n YYYY`.
>
> How can I achieve that?

This is the code used for generating the chart:

```
plt.plot(df_21d["Timestamp"], df_21d["Close"], label="Price", color="b")    

plt.title("BTC - 21 Dias")

plt.xlabel("Data")
plt.ylabel("Preco (em USD)")

plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

**Here's my data:**

*df_21d["Timestamp"]*

```
667   2016-05-27 08:00:00
668   2016-05-27 08:30:00
669   2016-05-27 09:00:00
670   2016-05-27 09:30:00
671   2016-05-27 10:00:00
Name: Timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

*df_21d["Close"]*

```
667    480.00
668    471.36
669    477.35
670    476.55
671    479.92
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

I dont know if I have to format `df_21d.Timestamp` or if it's a matplotlib configuration. Maybe formatting the timestamp and passing it as a vector using `plt.xticks()`... but I'm not sure about how do that...

Or maybe even inserting only the first, the last and the middle value for the x-axis, with something like:

```
plt.xaxis_labels = (df_21d["Timestamp"][1], 
             df_21d["Timestamp"][len(df_21d["Timestamp"])/2], 
             df_21d["Timestamp"][len(df_21d["Timestamp"])])
```

Comment: I know this is not a solution to your actual problem, but I would recommend you to think about using less ticks. 5-7 should be enough to give the reader a good impression of the scale and it makes your plot less cluttered.

Comment: @ian_itor I've updated my question. Is there any way to show - as you said - only 3 values in x-axis? I don't wanna use only 3 ticks, I wanna plot all ticks (don't wanna interpolate my data) but show only the first, last and the middle tick timestamp value in x-axis, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This answer might help you:
[Not write out all dates on an axis, Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452179/not-write-out-all-dates-on-an-axis-matplotlib)

Essentially, you can set the format of dates by setting the format:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d %m'))
```