# Re-order x-axis for timestamps after midnight - Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to `plot` a range of values from a `pandas` `df`. These values are taken from `Columns` that display the total number of values occurring at any point in time.

My attempt is below. The problem I'm having is the `x-axis` isn't formatted correctly in regards to values go past midnight. Values related to timestamps after midnight are `plotted` first instead of last. (Please see image below)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

d = ({
    'Time1' : ['8:00:00','10:30:00','12:40:00','16:25:00','22:30:00','1:31:00','2:15:00','2:20:00','2:30:00'],
    'Occurring1' : ['1','2','3','4','5','4','3','2','1'],
    'Time2' : ['8:10:00','10:10:00','13:40:00','16:05:00','21:30:00','1:11:00','3:00:00','3:01:00','6:00:00'],
    'Occurring2' : ['1','2','3','4','5','4','3','2','0'],
    'Time3' : ['8:05:00','11:30:00','15:40:00','17:25:00','23:30:00','1:01:00','6:00:00','6:00:00','6:00:00'],
    'Occurring3' : ['1','2','2','3','2','1','0','0','0'],
    'Time4' : ['9:50:00','10:30:00','14:40:00','18:25:00','20:30:00','0:31:00','2:35:00','6:00:00','6:00:00'],
    'Occurring4' : ['1','2','3','4','4','3','2','0','0'],
    'Time5' : ['9:00:00','11:30:00','13:40:00','17:25:00','00:30:00','2:31:00','6:00:00','6:00:00','6:00:00'],
    'Occurring5' : ['1','2','3','3','2','1','0','0','0'],                   
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df = df.astype({
    "Time1": np.datetime64,
    "Occurring1": np.int,
    "Time2": np.datetime64,
    "Occurring2": np.int,
    "Time3": np.datetime64,
    "Occurring3": np.int,
    "Time4": np.datetime64,
    "Occurring4": np.int,
    "Time5": np.datetime64,
    "Occurring5": np.int,    
})

all_times = df[["Time1", "Time2", "Time3",'Time4','Time5']].values

t_min = np.timedelta64(int(60*1e9), "ns")

time_grid = np.arange(all_times.min(), all_times.max(), 10*t_min, dtype="datetime64")
X = pd.Series(time_grid).dt.time.values
occurrences_grid = np.zeros((5, len(time_grid)))

for i in range(5):
    occurrences_grid[i] = griddata(
        points=df["Time%i" % (i+1)].values.astype("float"),
        values=df["Occurring%i" % (i+1)],
        xi=time_grid.astype("float"),
        method="linear"
    )

occ_min = np.min(occurrences_grid, axis=0)
occ_max = np.max(occurrences_grid, axis=0)
occ_mean = np.mean(occurrences_grid, axis=0)

plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.fill_between(X, occ_min, occ_max, color="blue")
plt.plot(X, occ_mean, c="white")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: If those times denote moments on two different days they should carry a date with them.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I just want to `plot` the `timestamps` though. Is it at all possible to do without the `date`?

Comment: So how do you imagine the axis to know that `02:00` should come after `10:30` if you don't specify the date of the respective times? That's what my first comment expressed already, so I guess you want to implement that and then potentially ask about any problem you encounter doing so.

Comment: I don’t _expect_ it to know. I was thinking to plot it with date time so the axis of formatted correctly and think play around with the xticks afterwards. Do you think the downvotes are really necessary?

Comment: I did not downvote, so I cannot comment on that. But my intuition would be that if you apply the first comment and state within the question why that wouldn't help, people would understand better what the question asks for and hence not downvote.

Comment: Ok. I’ll re-arrange it. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
df = df.astype({
    "Time1": np.datetime64,
    "Occurring1": np.int})
```

each time mark has the same date (`2019-03-05` is just the today's date). All elements of `all_times` have the same date too. And from here you "get the wrong curve" by using `time_grid = np.arange(all_times.min(), all_times.max(), 10*t_min, dtype="datetime64")`.

There are 2 strategies to circumvent that problem:

**Strategy A**

If you are happy with the data you see but are only unhappy because the after-midnight data are not there, where you would prefere it, then you can shift/roll the data. This approach does not change the way you extract the data to plot the graphic. I inserted the following steps:

1. determin the earliest time mark from `Time_i` (= the time where the time series should start). This is `t_start`
2. find out at which index of the time_grid t_start is. This gives `index`.
3. just before plotting shift/roll the arrays. But it will not work if you roll X too ! So use a surrogate time axis for X
4. *not shown: replace the labels of the x-axis using matplotlib* ([Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879842/how-can-i-change-datetime-format-of-x-axis-values-in-matplotlib-using-python))

This gives that (and code is below)

[image]

**Strategy B**

Since the time mark without the date is periodic, you run into the problem you have metioned. For the interpolation the time axis should be increasing monotonically. So the approach is: when interpolating with `scipy.interpolate.griddata(points, values, xi)` use for `points` and  `x1` surrogates that are increasing monotonically. For that you will have to adapt the procedure you determin `occurrences_grid`.

Here the code for strategy A.

```
d = ({
    'Time1' : ['8:00:00','10:30:00','12:40:00','16:25:00','22:30:00','1:31:00','2:15:00','2:20:00','2:30:00'],
    'Occurring1' : ['1','2','3','4','5','4','3','2','1'],
    'Time2' : ['8:10:00','10:10:00','13:40:00','16:05:00','21:30:00','1:11:00','3:00:00','3:01:00','6:00:00'],
    'Occurring2' : ['1','2','3','4','5','4','3','2','0'],
    'Time3' : ['8:05:00','11:30:00','15:40:00','17:25:00','23:30:00','1:01:00','6:00:00','6:00:00','6:00:00'],
    'Occurring3' : ['1','2','2','3','2','1','0','0','0'],
    'Time4' : ['9:50:00','10:30:00','14:40:00','18:25:00','20:30:00','0:31:00','2:35:00','6:00:00','6:00:00'],
    'Occurring4' : ['1','2','3','4','4','3','2','0','0'],
    'Time5' : ['9:00:00','11:30:00','13:40:00','17:25:00','00:30:00','2:31:00','6:00:00','6:00:00','6:00:00'],
    'Occurring5' : ['1','2','3','3','2','1','0','0','0'],                   
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df = df.astype({
    "Time1": np.datetime64,
    "Occurring1": np.int,
    "Time2": np.datetime64,
    "Occurring2": np.int,
    "Time3": np.datetime64,
    "Occurring3": np.int,
    "Time4": np.datetime64,
    "Occurring4": np.int,
    "Time5": np.datetime64,
    "Occurring5": np.int,    
})

all_times = df[["Time1", "Time2", "Time3",'Time4','Time5']].values
t_start = min(df["Time1"].iloc[0], df["Time2"].iloc[0], df["Time3"].iloc[0], 
              df["Time4"].iloc[0], df["Time5"].iloc[0])                                  # new: t_start
t_start = np.datetime64(t_start)                                                         # conversion pandas/numpy
t_min = np.timedelta64(int(60*1e9), "ns")
time_grid = np.arange(all_times.min(), all_times.max(), 10*t_min, dtype="datetime64")
index = np.argmax(time_grid>=t_start)                                                    # new: index to start the graphics
print('index');print(index,time_grid[index])
X = pd.Series(time_grid).dt.time.values
occurrences_grid = np.zeros((5, len(time_grid)))

for i in range(5):
    occurrences_grid[i] = griddata(
        points=df["Time%i" % (i+1)].values.astype("float"),
        values=df["Occurring%i" % (i+1)],
        xi=time_grid.astype("float"),
        method="linear"
    )

occ_min = np.min(occurrences_grid, axis=0)
occ_max = np.max(occurrences_grid, axis=0)
occ_mean = np.mean(occurrences_grid, axis=0)

def roll(X,occ_min,occ_max,occ_mean):                                                   # new: shift/roll the values
    return np.arange(len(X)), np.roll(occ_min,-index), np.roll(occ_max,-index), np.roll(occ_mean,-index)
                                                                                       # do not shift X but use a surrogate time axis

X,occ_min,occ_max,occ_mean = roll(X,occ_min,occ_max,occ_mean) 

fig, ax0 = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,4))
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.fill_between(X, occ_min, occ_max, color="blue")
plt.plot(X, occ_mean, c="white")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
fig.savefig('plot_model_2.png', transparency=True)
```

Comment: Add on: Since `Time_i` and `alle_times` DO include the date, problabley the most simple approach for strategy B is: (i) do the interpolation using the date, (ii) drop the date just for the final plotting.