# Pandas melt dataframe in terms of date time and fill all values NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe including all countries and datetime ranging from "1/22/20" to "2/22/20".

Here is my dataframe Column shown below.

```
Country 1/22/20 1/23/20 1/24/20 1/25/20 1/26/20 1/27/20 1/28/20 1/29/20 1/30/20...
```

I try to melt dataframe to get values in terms of datetime and country like

```
US 1/25/20 28
```

but all values defined as `NaN`

```
Australia   2020-01-22  NaN
```

How can I fix it?

Here is my code snippet

```
def meltDataFrame(df,id_vars,value_vars,var_name,value_name):
    return pd.melt(df,
        id_vars= id_vars,
        value_vars = value_vars,
        var_name= var_name,
        value_name= value_name)

data_df_melt = meltDataFrame(data_df.reset_index(),
        ['Country'],pd.date_range('1/22/20', '3/18/20', freq='D'),'Date','Total_Count')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is columns names are not datetimes.

So convert all columns names without first to datetimes:

```
df.columns = df.columns[:1].tolist() + pd.to_datetime(df.columns[1:]).tolist()
```

And then melt.

**Sample**:

```
print (df)
     Country  1/22/20  1/23/20  1/24/20
0  Australia       11       42       53

df.columns = df.columns[:1].tolist() + pd.to_datetime(df.columns[1:]).tolist()
print (df)
     Country  2020-01-22 00:00:00  2020-01-23 00:00:00  2020-01-24 00:00:00
0  Australia                   11                   42                   53
```

Comment: When I draw a plot , datetime is appeared like 2020-01-22T00:00:00.000000000. How can I get only 2020-01-22

Comment: @TonyBrand change my solution with `df.columns = df.columns[:1].tolist() + pd.to_datetime(df.columns[1:]).date.tolist()` and then use `data_df_melt = meltDataFrame(data_df.reset_index(),
        ['Country'],pd.date_range('1/22/20', '3/18/20', freq='D').date ,'Date','Total_Count')`

Comment: @TonyBrand - for convert datetimes to dates in columns and in `meltDataFrame` function

Comment: I use this code `data_df_melt = meltDataFrame(data_df.reset_index(), ['Country'],pd.date_range('1/22/20', '3/18/20', freq='D').date ,'Date','Total_Count')` but it doesn't work. I produces `NaN`

Comment: @TonyBrand - yes, because you forget for `df.columns = df.columns[:1].tolist() + pd.to_datetime(df.columns[1:]).date.tolist()` - there is already necessary create dates

Comment: It appeared again like `2020-01-22T00:00:00.000000000` in seaborn after I did what you said

Comment: @TonyBrand hmmm, is possible check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452179/not-write-out-all-dates-on-an-axis-matplotlib) ?

Comment: I forgot to remove date format code. After removing it , the issue is disappeared.