# How to have intervals in dates, so that dates are not overlapped?

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, time-series

```
# Add x-axis and y-axis
ax.bar(india.index.values,
       india['Confirmed'],
       color='purple')

# Set title and labels for axes
ax.set(xlabel="Date",
       ylabel="Confirmed cases",
       title="Confirmed cases in India")

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

I want the dates in intervals like 3/20/20, 3/30/2020, 4/10/2020, 4/25/2020,....

this is the dataset

```
           Country  Confirmed   
Date                
03/20/2020  India   244 
03/21/2020  India   330 
03/22/2020  India   396 
03/23/2020  India   499 
03/24/2020  India   536 
... ... ... ... ...
07/28/2020  India   1483156 
07/29/2020  India   1581963 
07/30/2020  India   1634746 
07/31/2020  India   1695988 
08/01/2020  India   1750723
```

[image]

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452179/not-write-out-all-dates-on-an-axis-matplotlib

Comment: Thanks, Jonas. It worked. I searched the whole internet for this.